# Linux: How to capture sheduled shutdown datetime and display it on Zenity Window?

Tags: scripts, shutdown, .desktop, zenity

Using a script I want to display my system's scheduled shutdown datetime on a Zenity window on the desktop.

The following code displays the scheduled date and time formatted. I want to take that date and time and display it on Zenity Message Window on the desktop.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f /run/systemd/shutdown/scheduled ]; then   perl -wne 'm/^USEC=(\d+)\d{6}$/ and printf("Shutting down at: %s\n", scalar localtime $1)' < /run/systemd/shutdown/scheduled; 
fi
```

How do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the message you created in a shell variable, then use that variable to display the message in a zenity dialog. A statement as

```
MESSAGE=$(/path/to/your/executable/script)
```

will run your script and store the output of your script in the variable 1 MESSAGE`.

That variable can then be displayed with:

```
zenity --info --text "$MESSAGE"
```

Comment: It works. :), but I had to create two different scripts to make this work. Is there way you can do all this with just one single script?